# connect to connect to pptp vpn just using terminal

Tags: linux, terminal, vpn

I want to create a pptp vpn client and connect to it using terminal. 
I created a connection using `pptp-setup` and then connect to it using ‍`pon‍‍` command. 
but the problem is my internet traffic does'nt route through this vpn connection.

Answer (score 2):

You can connect to Cisco VPN Server if your VPN Provider supports it.

```
pacman -S openconnect
openconnect <server address>
```

Answer (score 1):

just use `route` command like this :

```
 sudo route add default dev ppp0
```

replace ppp0 with your vpn connection name you find in `ifconfig`